# Imbalanced data classification using Random Forest in matlab

Tags: random-forest

I want to solve an imbalanced data classification, with small number of data points (approximately 600 ) with the ratio of true labels to false ,  1:12. Is there any function or matlab code for using Random forest for classification of imbalanced data? How should I access it and set the parameters? 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The function would be the same as the one for balanced data - TreeBagger or fitensemble. By default, either grows deep trees; the default minimal leaf size is 1 for classification. This typically gives you enough sensitivity to find a good decision boundary between the classes. The *default* decision boundary, at which the class posterior probabilities are equal, is most usually not what you want for imbalanced data. As I advised in your other post, use the perfcurve function to find the optimal threshold on the posterior probability for the minority class.

By the way, try MATLAB Answers http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers for MATLAB questions. I read that site much more often than this one.